# windows 7 - Where is Menu Start Folder Located? (documents, music, etc.)

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I need to know WHERE THE MENU START FOLDER IS LOCATED

I mean this menu :

[image]

Where is its folder located? (path)

I would like to do some stuff,
like add my custom folders to this menu, as normal folders, not collection
(I want to add about 5-6 folders)

But primarily I want to know the PATH

Comment: There is no folder containing these items in the system that you could modify. That's why the answers only provide alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14101/add-my-dropbox-to-your-windows-7-start-menu/) that details exactly what you want.

---

You can add it to the Start Menu… using a silly hack to the Libraries feature and renaming the `Recorded TV library` to a different name. It’s not a perfect solution, but you can access your folder this way and it just seems to belong there.

First things first, head into the Customize Start Menu panel by right-clicking on the start menu and using `Properties`, then make sure that Recorded TV is set to `Display as a link`.

[image]

Next, right-click on Recorded TV, choose Rename, and then change it.

[image]

Now you’ll want to right-click on that button again, and choose `Properties`, where you’ll see the Library locations in the list… the general idea is that you want to remove `Recorded TV`, and then add your *folder*.

[image]

Comment: In this way I'm not able to add the number of folders that I need and they result as "collection folders" and not as Normal Folders

Answer (score 0):

You can add or remove items, such as Computer, Control Panel, and Pictures, that appear on the right side of the Start menu. You can also change some items so that they appear as links or menus.

1. Open **Taskbar** and Start Menu Properties by clicking the **Start** button , clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and **Personalization**, and then clicking **Taskbar** and Start Menu.
2. Click the Start Menu tab, and then click Customize.
3. In the Customize Start Menu dialog box, select the options in the list that you want, click OK, and then click OK again.

If you want to add a folder to the right pane of the start menu, I would say it's **not** designed for this purpose (to show directly your custom folders), and if you still insist you should use a trick lick what the Tiago C has shown or I think a better way that is showing the **favorites menu** and simply adding the folder you want into it by a simple D & D :

[image]

[image]

However I suggest you to add folders to this part of the start menu :

[image]

That is simply done by a drag and drop and [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Folder-to-Start-Menu) is a more detailed reference to do this.

And finally you can have access to the programs from a path like this: 
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`.

Comment: I dont need to add folders to the left pane.

Comment: @Roger: Well, so you're provide two ways to do what you want so far :)

Comment: I still don't know the path of the menu that I mean

Comment: @Roger that menu does not have a path, it is stored as various registry settings. That is why you have to go to a special "Customize Start Menu" window to edit it.

Comment: @Roger I updated my answer that may be make my solution more clear and as a complement to the Scott's comment this is why I told you, you may use some tricks to do this.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain can you teel me more about the registry way: do you know some app that can do it, or tell me where I must to go in the registry

Comment: @Roger the "app to do it" is the Right click->Properties method both of the answers have already shown you how to do.